# Place social buttons in a row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have various social buttons for Twitter, Facebook and GitHub, etc. 
I would like them to all be in a row.
Here is the CSS for my social buttons:

```
.social-buttons {
    text-align: left;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.social-facebook, .social-github, .social-twitter {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 18%;
}
.social-twitter-2 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 28%;
}
```

In the CSS that I have I had set them all to be displayed in an inline-block.
Can I have help figuring out how to place them all in one row so they cannot move around from that row?
Also, can someone add my screenshot to the post: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lg9da719y2gsyla/screenshot_social-buttons.jpg ?
If it is relevant I'm using Bootstrap 2.3.2, at the moment of writing.

Answer (score 0):

Have all your social network buttons in ul tag. And paste this code in your css so that all your social network buttons are in one row.

```
#list li
{
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. The two twitter buttons get displayed below the jumbotron.

Comment: I notice that you're not using the social id for the ul tag. Also I would suggest having the ul tag outside hub-jumbotron-text div

Comment: I did that and still, it won't work. Added a little more CSS to set a max-height for the iframe element to 20px, and now it displays in the same area but not on the same row

Comment: I also notice that in the ul tag there is a div in between the 4 li tags. And there's an invisible facebook button as far as I can see. What's happening there?

Comment: the div is for facebook reset, facebook says to add it on their website. The FB button seems to not want to work...

Comment: Your div should only have li tags because the icons seem to scatter all over the place when I look at them in the element inspector.